# Как конвертировать ответ от Web-сервера с помощью Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Запрос к серверу выглядит так

```
 @GET("GetCardInfo/{phoneNumber}")
Call<CardInfo> getCardInfo(
        @Header("Authorization") String auth,
        @Path("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber
);
```

Класс CardInfo:

```
 public class CardInfo {

    private String phoneNumber;
    private String secondName;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private int bonusCount;
    private int bonusAmount;
    //геттеры и сеттеры
```

Обработка ответа сервера:

```
Call<String> call = mRetrofit.getCardInfo(auth, phoneNumber);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.errorBody() );
                        return;
                    }

                    String cardInfo = response.body().toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + cardInfo);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage() );
                }
            });
```

От web-сервера приходит ответ вида:

```
81234567890;Иванов;Иван;Иванович;01.01.2020 0:00:00;;1000;1000
```

Т.е. это не gson-ответ, а просто строка, поэтому при попытке распарсить её при помощи GsonConverterFactory я получаю

```
onFailure: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1
```

А если в Call поменять CardInfo на String, получаю ошибку:

```
onFailure: Unexpected value at line 1 column 13 path $
```

Подскажите, в какую сторону смотреть и что нужно почитать, чтобы решить эту задачу. Спасибо.

Comment: А сервер поддерживает ответ в json-формате?

Comment: нет, ответ приходит только в таком виде, доступа к серверу у меня нет :)

Comment: Посмотрите API сервера - возможно, есть какой-то параметр запроса, отвечающий за формат. Либо писать свой парсер ответа. =)

Comment: А свой парсер должен наследовать какой то класс? Где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Так, в ответе из запроса создавайте объект класса CardInfo. Строку с разделителем ; распарсите и записывайте в свойства объекта.

Comment: А я же написал в вопросе, что при попытке получить String, получаю ошибку onFailure: Unexpected value at line 1 column 13 path $ или я как то по другому это должен делать?

Comment: Уберите `GsonConverterFactory`, получите ответ строкой: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37589828 и разберите строку, например c помощью `String.split(";")'

Comment: Да, я слишком сложно думал, то что нужно, спасибо, не вижу, как сделать ваш комментарий ответом?